# Why does an author use a comma in the sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I need your help. I’ve been learning English for now almost 3 years and can say with confidence that I’m quite good at it – although sometimes struggle with punctuation.

I’ve got two sentences (taken from a newspaper and a book):

1. Alito and Thomas repeated a position on mandatory **jurisdiction (,) and** said they would not stop the Electoral College from voting Monday.
2. He got a Maine newspaper called the Portland ***Press-Herald ()  and*** watched it for items concerning a small southern Maine town…

I can't put my head around it – why there’s a comma in the first phrase but no comma in the second one? What am I missing about it? I would really love to know why it is so.
Thanks.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences?rq=1).

Comment: @fev That link is about compound sentences with 2 independent clauses. These sentences have either a null subject in the second clause, or  a compound predicate, but  I'll wait for a better grammarian than me to weigh in...

Comment: I  don't think it would be wrong to leave out the comma. The writer just chose to use one.

Comment: Duplicate of [Comma usage with compound predicates](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266810/comma-usage-with-compound-sentences) The comma is optional here. Useful for those with smaller lungs. And as a parsing aid.

Comment: To be fair, the pause signalled by a comma _could_ correspond to to a more 'abrupt', disjointed coordination, perhaps with consequence ('he sprained his ankle, and had to withdraw' vs 'he ate his scone and drank his coffee').